# Calling a CSS design causes "expected assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following CSS class

```
.blinking {
    animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{     color: #100;    }
    49%{    color: transparent; }
    50%{    color: transparent; }
    99%{    color:transparent;  }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
```

and I call it in my javascript like this

```
<span className="blinking">
            Winner
             </span>
```

but it throws this error saying

"expected assignment or function call and instead got an expression"

Not sure what the error is because my other css classes are called like this as well, and they work.

Comment: That's a ruleset and an at-rule. There is no such thing as a CSS class.

Comment: "expected assignment or function call and instead got an expression" — This is a JavaScript error message. It has nothing to do with the CSS, and there is nothing obvious in the JSX that would cause it. I think you're looking at the wrong bit of code.

Comment: @Quentin unfortunately when I launch my react app thats the line it points to that causes the error. Ill look around

Comment: Possibly you haven't transpiled the JSX into JS.

Comment: @Quentin ok so I just tried it with completely different css and it throws the same error this means its the JS correct?

Comment: It being a JS error indicates that it is the JS.